# Which ebook reader should someone aiming to brush up his vocabulary pick?

Tags: windows, linux, ebook

I am looking for an e-book reader that comes with a dictionary. If I select a word I want to get the meaning pop up, and it must be ordered by relevancy based on the context in which the word appears. Anything out there like that?

EDIT:
The matrix below is something that I am looking for. Only issue is that it list Devices, rather than software. PC Software, something  that is cross platform and works on Linux would also be great. I have looked as some Firefox plug-ins that does dictionary lookups, and have tried converting e-books into HTML and reading through the web browser. The user experience was terrible, and it was a pain.
http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/E-book_Reader_Matrix

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Super User is intended for computer hardware and software related questions.  Questions about consumer electronics devices such as e-book readers, phones and MP3 players are considered off-topic.  Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) and check out [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Looking for PC software, not devices. Will update appropriately.

Comment: Retagged the question to make it clearer at a glance that this is a software question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Word Web](http://wordweb.info/free/) is what you are looking for.  You can easily look up words in any program when using it.